# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdf2docx'

Tags: python

Look at this simple PDF to Docx converter, it needs pdf2docx module, although I have installed it manually using this code (py -m pip install pdf2dox) in CMD but still, it says (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdf2docx')

What am I doing wrong here, please?

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Code:

```
from pdf2docx import Converter, parse
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import messagebox


def choose_and_convert_file():
    pdf_file = f"{askopenfilename()}"
    if pdf_file == "":
        messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Please choose a file!")

    else:
        file = pdf_file[:-4]
        word_file = f"{file}.docx"
    # Converter Method
        cv = Converter(pdf_file)
        cv.convert(word_file, start=0, end=None)
        cv.close()

# Parse Method
# parse(pdf_file, word_file, start=0, end=None)

def space():
    space = Label(text="", bg="black")
    space.pack()



root = Tk()

root.title("PDF to Word Converter")
root.geometry("450x450")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.config(bg="black")
root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')

space()
space()
space()

img = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
pic = Label(root, image=img, bg="black")
pic.pack()

space()
space()
space()
space()
choose_file = Button(width=23, height=1, bg="black", fg="white", text=" Choose and Convert",
                      font=("jost", 11, "bold"), command=choose_and_convert_file)
choose_file.pack()


space()
space()
space()
space()
space()
space()
space()
dev_label = Label(root, text="Developed by Totenkopf ", bg="black", fg="#CC1B25", font=("jost", 11))
dev_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you see if the module exists when you run `pip list`

Comment: Looks like you've installed the module in python `3.10` but you're running python `3.9`

Comment: @RadioActive, I just did, and no it doesn't exist.

Comment: @RadioActive, I have so many issues with these modules, this always happens, how to fix that?

Comment: So I'm guessing you've definitely installed the module in python 3.10 but you're running python 3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pip is installing all your packages in `Python 3.10`,

I would recommend that you locate the `python.exe` for python 3.10 and then execute your command like this:

```
C:\users\......\python\python310\python.exe main.py
```

Alternatively, If you already have environment variables configured for python, you can run:

```
python main.py
```

Comment: The system cannot find the path specified << This is what I got when tried to run with >>  C:\Python310\python.exe main.py

Comment: That's because Python isn't isn't installed on that location try: `C:\users\......\python\python310\python.exe main.py`

Answer (score 0):

Solved, there was a bit of confusion I fell into, I was running my Python file with Python3.8 and I was using  `py -m pip install ModuleName` for installing the missing module.

So instead, I used:

```
python -m pip install ModuleName
```

Comment: Exactly as I pointed out!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

- make sure that all words are spelled correctly,
- try different keywords,
- try more general keywords,
- try fewer keywords.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).